# Construct nested unordered list in HTML using flare.json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

How do I construct the below `flare.json` file to a nested unordered list in HTML? I am planning to use the nested unordered list to display charts.

Can someone guide me on how to convert?

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "analytics",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                        {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                        {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                        {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "graph",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                        {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                        {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                        {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                        {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "optimization",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think the JSON you've pasted here is missing some closing brackets

Comment: @DevMehta Sorry about that i just fixed it.

Comment: Try a recursive function. Please post the code from your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some ambiguity in your question, but here's my stab at it. Let me know if it's not what you're looking for.

Here's the relevant code:

```
function pprint(o) {
  if(typeof o != 'object') {
    return o.toString(); /* Note: this check won't work for javascript in general, but should be okay for the result of JSON.parse */
  }
  var open = '<ul>', close = '</ul>', html = '', notArray = true;
  if(Array.isArray(o)) {
    open = '<ol>';
    close = '</ol>';
    notArray = false;
  }
  $.each(o, function(k,v){
    html += '<li>';
    if(notArray) {
      html += k+': ';
    }
    html += pprint(v)+'</li>';
  });
  return open+html+close;
}
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/devm33/pen/lspjh/